# Intel Rapid Store

Tags: storage

I am not sure if I have a port problem, HD, or MB issue.  I have a Windows Home Server with six 2 TB HDs in an RAID 5 configuration.  One day, I noticed the #6 HD was showing missing and there was message below stating that here was an Internal Empty Port 2.  I shut down the server, reset the #6 HD on the back of the drive and on the MB itself.  I restarted the server and it showed green for about 45 minutes...then changed to missing again.  I have repeated this several times with the same result.  I am suspecting the HD or maybe the MB.  This server barely gets used....maybe this is the 5th time I have used it...any ideas?  I can email you before and after pics

Comment: Hdd a single port is unlikely bad; you can switch ports being used see if the problem follows the port or the hdd